# Google Script MailApp - Setting Timer

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers, google-forms

Are there any possibilities that I can control how long it takes after a form has been submitted before it will send an email out?

Currently, my code is working with a `onFormSubmit` function. So whenever a form is submitted and I have google script that has `IF statements` which checks for a range of values.

I want to improve the code but I can't think of any for the past few days. My plan is to send an email lets say, 10 minutes after the form is submitted. Let say, the form submitted has typos in it and one of the values isn't supposed to trigger an email send but instead it does due to the typo.

So now, I want to edit that value to the correct value which is within the accepted range. If this is being edited within that 10 minutes and is being checked again that it is actually within the range, then the email will not be sent. Is there any way this can be done? I have read up a bit about the function onEdit but it does not really cater for my requirements.

Answer (score 1):

### A solution I can think of:

`onFormSubmit` run a  [Clock trigger builder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder) that will, lets say [after](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder#after(Integer)) the chosen amount of time run a function. Within this function you can verify if an edit to the form has taken place (retrieve the form submit data from the [destination spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/destination-type)) and send an email if required.

Comment: So since my function is ``onFormSubmit``  

I'll start with:  
``ScriptApp.newTrigger("onFormSubmit")  
.timeBased()  
.after(600000) // 10mins  
.create();  
``
  
Am I correct? Then within that onFormSubmit function, I have something to check if there is any edits?

Comment: This is the idea, but the nesting should be like `onFormSubmit(){ScriptApp.newTrigger("runOnTrigger") .timeBased() .after(600000) // 10mins .create();} runOnTrigger(){...//if there are no edits - send email ...}`. That is on Form submit you build a time trigger which fires after ten minutes and runs a second function checking if there have been edits.

Comment: Does this method require me to have a trigger event created manually through the stopwatch icon?

Comment: No, the trigger event will be the form submit which will lead to the creation of the time based trigger programmatically. Just that the on form submit trigger is an installable one - this means that is not enough to call the function `onFormSubmit()`, but rather you would need to go from the UI to `Edit->Current project's triggers` and create a new trigger with the event type `on form submit` and bound to the function `onFormSubmit()` or whatever you want to call it.

Comment: Got it. I give a go at this. Thanks.

Comment: I tried this with 60000 which is equivalent to 1 minute. I entered a number that is out of range and not edit it. The email did not send. I tried doing the same but then editing it, still it did not send an email. However, upon trying initial code without time trigger, it worked.

Comment: The main drawback I can think of for this solution is that depending on how many form submits, you might end up building a lot of triggers, while the limit is 20 triggers per script:  https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas  I suggest you to build into `runOnTrigger()` a function to delete the old trigger when you don't need it anymore: This means that after your reach this limit, you need to delete old triggers manually.

Comment: What do you mean by entering a number? You entered it manually in the spreadsheet or by filling out and submitting a Google Form? And how did you implement within runOnTrigger() the condition to check if the response has been edited?

Comment: Apologies, I mixed up. I used the Google Form that comes with the spreadsheet. I entered a value for 1 of the question that is out of range, it didn't trigger any email send which its suppose to. I'm trying without editing first to check if the time trigger actually works. After waiting for up to 5minutes, no email was sent.

Comment: You can view all your triggers if you go to Edit->Current project's triggers. So, if your on Form Submit trigger fired correctly and built the time trigger currently - both should appear in the list. I assume that you incorporated into the `runOnTrigger()` function a method to send an email? You can also just incorporate a log to test if the problem arises from the trigger and from the way you implemented the email sending function

Comment: Yes I incorporated the email sending in ``runOnTrigger();`` and my ``onFormSubmit`` trigger did run also.

Comment: So, check in the project triggers view if your timeBased trigger was built correctly within onFormSubmit()

Comment: Can I have ``function onFormSubmit(e){
function onEdit(v)}`` together?

Comment: Not like this. If you call an onEdit function within another function (correct syntax: `function onFormSubmit(e){ onEdit(v)}`), the function `onEdit` will be called on Form submit - but manually, not related to an onEdit event. You can install however several triggers (e.g. `onFormSubmit` and `onEdit`), bound to the same function through Edit->Current project's triggers->New trigger. Not sure though what you want to do with it.

Comment: I would want to have the form checked with some ``if statements`` and send an email after 1min trigger. But if within that 1min, if my code detects there is an response edit(say that the first submission has typos) on the last entered form responses, it will not send the email.

Comment: This is why I suggest you to use the the clock trigger. You can push on Form Submit the reponses into ScripProperties and call the clock trigger that will retrieve after 1 min the response again, compare it against the one that was stored in script properties and send an email if there was no change. See here about script properties: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57799074/return-next-element-from-an-array-in-googlesheets-using-scripts/57803530?noredirect=1#comment102060460_57803530