# Return next element from an array in googlesheets using scripts

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a list of names in a google sheet. I'm trying to create a function in google apps scripts that outputs the next name in the list to a different cell in the spreadsheet. Once I've returned each name, I want to go back to the beginning.

I've tried to use a for loop as well, but then the script just loops through every item, and I end up with the just the last item being returned.

```
   function returnNextName() {
       var nameList =
       SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("My 
       Homeroom").getRange(2, 1, 22).getValues();

       var outputCell = 
       SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("My 
       Homeroom").getRange(1, 4);

       var i = 0; 
       i = i + 1;
       i = i%nameList.length;

       var nextName = outputCell.setValue(nameList[i]);
     }
```

My goal is that every time I run the function, I will get the next name in the list. However, I only ever get the first name.

Comment: Use `PropertiesService`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every time you call the script you redefine

```
       var i = 0; 
       i = i + 1;
       i = i%nameList.length;
```

So your element `nameList[i]` will be always the same.

To avoid this, you need to use [PropertiesService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service), as suggested by TheMaster.

`ScriptProperties` allows you to store the last index in the script properties and retrieve and modify it every time you use the script.

### Sample:

```
    if(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getKeys().length==0){ // first time you run the script
       PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('i', 0);
      }   
    var i = Number(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('i'))%nameList.length;
    outputCell.setValue(nameList[i][0]);
    i++;
    PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('i', i);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't even know about PropertiesService. My script now works perfectly.